# CSS3 and HTML5 Hover Popup Box

Tags: html, css

Hi all I am currently trying to develop an HTML5 and CSS3 website. What I want to be able to do is when a user hovers over an input area of the website I want to be able to display a little pop up message next to the mouse position to display information to the user.

Is this possible, if not with HTML5 and CSS3 but using something else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a very simplistic solution I use as a base with my forms.

```
<style>
.help {
    background-color: #FFFF73;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.help_link:hover + span {
    display: inline;
}
</style>

<form>
    <label>Input: <input type="text" name="text" /></label> <a href="#" class="help_link">Help</a> <span class="help">Some help here on this input field.</span><br />
    <label>Input: <input type="text" name="text2" /></label> <a href="#" class="help_link">Help</a> <span class="help">Some help here on this input field.</span><br />
</form>
```

The usual disclaimers apply: this is a base, will not work in IE without an external library to add advanced selectors, border-radius not supported in Firefox 3.5, etc.

Comment: Excellent this works really well just what I was looking for. Quick question, on my input box I am doing a scale app and adding a box shaddow when the text box gains focus. However, once it has gained border I get a thick black border that appears that I can't seem to get to go away.

Comment: Set the input to `border: none;` then add the border on `input:focus` -- that way the input ONLY has a border when it is clicked on. If it's still not working post your code.

Answer (score 4):

```html
<input type="text" title="info for user here"/>
```

You can hover over an input text field and the title will allow a tool-tip type message pop up.

Comment: Simple and useful!